# Tolerate certain characters in RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, string-parsing, null-character

I am writing a message formatting parser that has the capability (among others) to parse links. This specific case requires parsing a link in the from of `<url|linkname>` and replacing that text with just the `linkname`. The issue here is that both `url` or `linkname` may or may not contain `\1` or `\2` characters anywhere in any order (at most one of each though). I want to match the pattern but keep the "invalid" characters. This problem solves itself for `linkname` as that part of the pattern is just `([^\n+])`, but the `url` fragment is matched by a much more complicated pattern, more specifically the URL validation pattern from [is.js](http://is.js.org). It would not be trivial to modify the whole pattern manually to tolerate `[\1\2]` everywhere, and I need the pattern to preserve those characters as they are used for tracking purposes (so I can't simply just `.replace(/\1|\2/g, "")` before matching).

If this kind of matching is not possible, is there some automated way to reliably modify the RegExp to add `[\1\2]{0,2}` between every character match, add `\1\2` to all `[chars]` matches, etc.

This is the `url` pattern taken from `is.js`:

```
/(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?/i
```

This pattern was adapted for my purposes and for the `<url|linkname>` format as follows:

```
let namedUrlRegex = /<((?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?)\|([^\n]+)>/ig;
```

The code where this is used is here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tupster24/9Lnf64ox/1/)

Examples for clarification (`...` represents the `namedUrlRegex` variable from above, and `$2` is the capture group that captures `linkname`):

```
Current behavior:
"<googl\1e.com|Google>".replace(..., "$2") // "<googl\1e.com|Google>" WRONG
"<google.com|Goo\1gle>".replace(..., "$2") // "Goo\1gle"              CORRECT
"<not_\1a_url|Google>".replace(..., "$2") // "<not_\1a_url|Google>"   CORRECT

Expected behavior:
"<googl\1e.com|Google>".replace(..., "$2") // "Google" (note there is no \1)
"<google.com|Goo\1gle>".replace(..., "$2") // "Goo\1gle"
"<not_\1a_url|Google>".replace(..., "$2") // "<not_\1a_url|Google>"
```

> Note the same rules for `\1` apply to `\2`, `\1\2`, `\1...\2`, `\2...\1` etc
>
> Context: This is used to normalize a string from a WYSIWYG editor to the length/content that it will display as, preserving the location of the current selection (denoted by `\1` and `\2` so it can be restored after parsing). If the "caret" is removed completely (e.g. if the cursor was in the URL of a link), it will select the whole string instead. Everything works as expected, except for when the selection starts or ends in the url fragment.
>
> *Edit for clarification*: I *only* want to change a segment in a string if it follows the format of `<url|linkname>` where `url` matches the URL pattern (tolerating `\1`, `\2`) and `linkname` consists of non-`\n` characters. If this condition is not met within a `<...|...>` string, it should be left *unaltered* as per the `not_a_url` example above.

Comment: Why in *expected behaviors* third example output should be `<not_\1a_url|Google>` while you want to replace entire matched string with `linkname` which is `Google`?

Comment: Because `not_a_url` is not a url. I still want to incorporate the URL regex, just a version that tolerates `\1` and `\2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a RegEx that matches all "symbols" in the expression. One quirk of this is that it expects `:`, `=`, `!` characters to be escaped, even outside of a `(?:...)`, `(?=...)`, `(?!...)` expression. This is addressed by escaping them before processing.

[`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Tupster24/vu46j5wt/27/)

```
let r = /(\\.|\[.+?\]|\w|[^\\\/\[\]\^\$\(\)\?\*\+\{\}\|\+\:\=\!]|(\{.+?\}))(?:((?:\{.+?\}|\+|\*)\??)|\??)/g;

let url = /((?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?)/

function tolerate(regex, insert) {
    let first = true;
        // convert to string
    return regex.toString().replace(/\/(.+)\//, "$1").
        // escape :=!
        replace(/((?:^|[^\\])\\(?:\\)*\(\?|[^?])([:=!]+)/g, (m, g1, g2) => g1 + (g2.split("").join("\\"))).
        // substitute string
        replace(r, function(m, g1, g2, g3, g4) {
            // g2 = {...} multiplier (to prevent matching digits as symbols)
            if (g2) return m;
            // g3 = multiplier after symbol (must wrap in parenthesis to preserve behavior)
            if (g3) return "(?:" + insert + g1 + ")" + g3;
            // prevent matching tolerated characters at beginning, remove to change this behavior
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                return m;
            }
            // insert the insert
            return insert + m;
        }
    );
}

alert(tolerate(url, "\1?\2?"));
```